# unix process infinite

Tags: unix, process

I am wondering what happens in a program that just has a `while(1);` in the `main()` function when compiled with g++ on unix. When I run the program, I am seeing 0% cpu usage. Why is this? Shouldn't it hog up the cpu?

Is the compiler optimizing this somehow? By putting a yield_processor like system call that context switches out?

The code is compiled with g++ using default optimization (just compiled as `g++ source.cpp`)

```
int main()
{
  while(1);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What optimization level are you using? ("-O", "-O2", "-O3"?)

Comment: Post code example with compiler flags.

Comment: How are you measuring CPU usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As no dependecies are shown in the while() body, gcc produces an empty trigraph for this piece of code. Now, depending on standard flags you're actually using (also, check env. variables CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, if in *nix environment), the compiler doesn't produce the asm "hogging" code.

Just check after doing `g++ -S source.cpp` the source.s file (containing ASM code) if the loop has been produced or not.

Here's my output with no optimization flags by g++ (GCC) 4.5.0 20090910 (experimental):

```
    .text
.globl _main
_main:
LFB0:
    pushq   %rbp
LCFI0:
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
LCFI1:
L2:
    jmp L2
LFE0:
    .section __TEXT,__eh_frame,coalesced,no_toc+strip_static_syms+live_support
EH_frame1:
    .set L$set$0,LECIE1-LSCIE1
    .long L$set$0
LSCIE1:
    .long   0x0
    .byte   0x1
    .ascii "zPR\0"
    .byte   0x1
    .byte   0x78
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x6
    .byte   0x9b
    .long   ___gxx_personality_v0+4@GOTPCREL
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0xc
    .byte   0x7
    .byte   0x8
    .byte   0x90
    .byte   0x1
    .align 3
LECIE1:
.globl _main.eh
_main.eh:
LSFDE1:
    .set L$set$1,LEFDE1-LASFDE1
    .long L$set$1
LASFDE1:
    .long   LASFDE1-EH_frame1
    .quad   LFB0-.
    .set L$set$2,LFE0-LFB0
    .quad L$set$2
    .byte   0x0
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$3,LCFI0-LFB0
    .long L$set$3
    .byte   0xe
    .byte   0x10
    .byte   0x86
    .byte   0x2
    .byte   0x4
    .set L$set$4,LCFI1-LCFI0
    .long L$set$4
    .byte   0xd
    .byte   0x6
    .align 3
LEFDE1:
    .constructor
    .destructor
    .align 1
    .subsections_via_symbols
```

This code hogs my CPU as expected (on Mac OSX 10.6.1).

Comment: looks like i am getting a loop from the compiler at both O0 and O3.

Comment: post your .s file differences, mostly the "label: jmp label" section

Answer (score 0):

You either have a bug in your code, too much optimization (not likely), or are misreading your cpu usage.

In any case, you are right.  It should "hog up the cpu."

Answer (score 0):

It's not strictly against the rules for your compiler to do something clever with this code. Under the "as if" rule, there's no way for your program to tell if it's actually spinning in a loop, or just sleeping.

I'd like to hear more about what version of GCC you're running, and on what OS. GCC-4 on Mac OS X doesn't do anything special with this code.

Of course, your OS might have a limit set for CPU usage by one process. I think the process would stop in that case, though.

Comment: st=i486-linux-gnu --target=i486-linux-gnu
gcc version 4.3.3 (Ubuntu 4.3.3-5ubuntu4)